# Robot Frame work Error Importing test library 'Requestslibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Requestslibrary' and 'JSONlibrary'

Tags: robotframework

I have two files one for keywords and other one is to run the actual test case

testkeywords.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Requestslibrary
Library  JSONlibrary
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
${Base_URL}  http://www.thetestingworldapi.com/

*** Keywords ***
Get Student Name
    [Arguments]  ${id}
    create session  Get_student_details  ${base_url}
    ${response}=    get request  Get_student_details  api/studentsDetails/${id}
    #log to console  ${response.content}
    ${json_res}=    to json  ${response.content}
    #log to console  ${json_res}
    @{first_name_list}=  get value from json  ${json_res}  data.first_name
    ${first_name}=  get from list  ${first_name_list}  0
    [return]  ${first_name}



sample.robot



*** Settings ***
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  JSONLibrary
Library  Collections
Resource  Resources/testkeywords.robot

*** Variables ***
${id}  56841

*** Test Cases ***
TC_01
    Get Student Name  ${id}
```

I am getting the error Error "Importing test library 'Requestslibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Requestslibrary"

but the sample file is ruining without any issues , while importing the same libraries

Comment: have you tried doing  `pip install robotframework-requests` ?

Comment: Yes , when inam running the sample.robot no error

Comment: Are you referring to an IDE like eclipse or RIDE?

Comment: yes i am using pycharm